# Google Cloud Shell error: package com.google.common.base does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Maven Java project that build and run good locally, uploaded folders to the Google Cloud Shell and trying to compile, I got the following errors.

```
 error: package com.google.common.base does not exist
```

Can anyone point me to the wright direction?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here.
https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/setup

I added the following to the POW.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
  <version>16.4.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```